# Calculate fundamental group of a polygon

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm stuck finding the fundamental group of this polygon $P$, where the edges with the same label identify each other.

[image]

My attempt was by Van Kampen's theorem, setting $U_1 = P- \{ p \}$,  with $p \in \mathring{P}$, $U_2 = \mathring{P}$ and $U_0 = U_1 \cap U_2 = \mathring{P} - \{p\}$. $U_2$ is homotopy equivalent to a point because is convex, so $\pi_1(U_2) = 1$. $U_0$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{S}_1$ by "expanding" the point and shrinking the points near to the border. $U_1$ is homotopic to the boundary, but I have no idea what becomes after the identifications. I think that the $a$'s below the picture can be glued, so the pentagon becomes a triangle that becomes a circle after the identifications, but I'm not sure.
Any hint?

PD: Is this the first time posting in here and my english is poor. Sorry if you can't understand my writing.

Comment: Hint: First nail down how many vertices there are left after doing all the identifications, then connect them up with the 5 a's and b's. Some will disappear through identification, but my guess is that you'll be left with a few circles wedge summed together.